# Why my M.2 NVMe Drive isn't being detected on BIOS after a BSOD?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, nvme, m.2

I'm having an issue with my M.2 NVMe SSD of my laptop. I have an Acer Aspire A515-43 R19L, and the NVMe Drive is the default one, SK Hynix 128GB.

The thing is, it's not being detected on the BIOS. After the Acer logo, a "No bootable device" just appears.

Short story is, after a full charge I decided to connect my 4G Mobile Router over USB. Decided to turn off Wi-Fi (because I was gonna use it over USB) and after a few minutes, a BSOD appears with the message "KERNEL DATA INPAGE ERROR". After that, W10 Repair Screen shows up. I was kinda shocked, didn't thought it was a major problem (I had to investigate in the moment, not after) and turned off my laptop. After powering back on, the "No bootable device" was there, and my NVMe Drive wasn't being detected on the BIOS.

What could have happened? After reading on some threads, looks like the driver of the NVMe could have been corrupted. But this is my first NVMe, so I don't have a clue of this.

Can someone help me with this? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for reading! Attached are some pictures of the BIOS and the No bootable device screen. (The NVMe was connected all the time).

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHINq.jpg

Comment: Go into BIOS and then reset BIOS to Default values. Save, exit and start up.  Does it start now?

Comment: Nothing yet. It's liek its not there, or not being recognized. But it's connected, this happened after that BSOD.

Comment: Not a driver issue. BIOS/EFI doesn't rely on drivers to detect drives. It's more likely that something happened to your SSD drive and it's bit the dust. Either that, or the motherboard has had some sort of hardware failure that is preventing it from accessing the drive.

Comment: BSODs almost always happen due to hardware issues. Troubleshooting a busted M.2 drive isn't much different than troubleshooting any other hard drive. If BIOS can't detect the drive, then either the motherboard or hard drive is failing. Using another PC to test with can help confirm which failed.